# how to apply background color for text tightly? (HTML5, CSS3)

Tags: html, css

```
   <!-- 6장 연습문제 4 -->
<html lang = "ko">
    <head>
        <meta charset = "UTF-8">
        <style>
        img{margin-left: auto; margin-right: auto; display: block;

        }
        .hyper{
            text-decoration-line:none; 
        }

        .text{
            border : 1px solid black;
            text-align: center;
            color:black;

        }
        .text:hover{

            background-color:yellow;
            color: red;
            text-decoration-line:none;
        }

        </style>
    </head>

    <body>
        <img src = "images/book.png" >
        <a href = "http://naver.com" class = "hyper">
        <p class = "text">[책 자세히 보기]</p> </a>

    </body>
</html>
```

I want to add background color only under text when cursored
[image: Original image]

like this.
but it worked like this ↓ 
[image: What I want]
I thought border might be solution 
but it was same, too long, get out from text.

how to solve this problem? give me the solution plz !

Comment: Your image was broken. By the way,  Read this: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add new div, and put your `<p>` into div. Set `text-align` attribute to div.

```
<html lang="ko">
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <style>
            img{margin-left: auto; margin-right: auto; display: block;

            }
            .hyper{
                text-decoration-line:none;
            }

            .text{
                display: inline-block;
                border : 1px solid black;
                color:black;

                vertical-align: middle;


            }
            .text:hover{

                background-color:yellow;
                color: red;
                text-decoration-line:none;
            }

            div {
                text-align: center;
            }

        </style>
    </head>

    <body>
    <img src="images/book.png">

    <div>
        <a href="http://naver.com" class="hyper">
            <p class="text">[책 자세히 보기]</p>
        </a>
    </div>

    </body>
    </html>
```

Comment: wow it works perfectly. thank you. could i get  knowledge about this problem? like article.. how does it work?

Comment: There is so many solutions and this is one of them. In this example, I used div parent and set text-align: center, because it affects it's children (not itself).

Answer (score 0):

Check the width of the text class element.

The block element has a width value of 100%.

Use display: inline-block to solve this.

The text is a p element with a block attribute by default.

The width value has 100%.

Check the text element for display: inline-block,

Try centering text-align: center

Comment: Please write in english. Share your knowledge globally.

Comment: thank you for answer. display:inlie-block; worked great. tight background color for text. but then text-align:center didn't work :-/

Comment: also thank you for knowledge how it's work. about width and in-line  attribute I'm really beginner to css

Comment: Add `width: 200px;` and `margin: 0 auto;` to the `.text` css. Or something like `margin: 50px auto 0 35%;` if you want some sort of alignment. Throw in some `padding: 15px;` give it some love.

Answer (score 0):

Second answer is good because if we use for display:inline-block it will be effect on related div space which that taken.